# How to specify when not to fire astatement?

Tags: esper

How do i specify when not to fire a statement, something like the following:

```
select a.timestamp from pattern 
[every a = A -> ( not timer:at (0, 6:12, *, *, *) and not timer:at (0, 16:20, *, *, *))];
```

I would like to specify all ranges when not to fire the statement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A crontab is not a condition that is false. It is rather a definition at what time it fires, as time advances, based on the time it starts from.

The question is really what your requirement is. Is there a time period where there should be no firings? What is the "and"+"or" relationship between the schedules? Just make an example based on requirements and not throw some design out there and expect people to guess what you may have wanted.

Comment: Sorry I complicate things, I though about it and really all I need is to specify times I dont want a firing. Is it possible to use "not" with the "timer:at" ? or any similar expressions like "not timer:at()"

Comment: i changed the OP. I want to specify when not to fire the statement.

Comment: It should fire outside the the specified ranges so if it says (* 16:20 * * * ) it should fire outside the range of 16:20 and if I add a new timer to the existing one (* 10:15 * * *) it should fire outside both these ranges 16:20 and 10:15

Comment: So if i added a new condition to the same statement (* 16:20 * * * ) ->(* 14:21 * * * ) they overlap but it dosent matter since its supposed to fire outside those ranges

Comment: Fire how often and when? Lets say its "2001-01-01 08:00:00.000" right now. An event A comes in. When should it fire?

Comment: it should fire every day when the time is not between 16pm and 20pm and also not when between 14pm and 21pm all days for ever. The date above it fires since its outside of 16 and 20 and 14 and 21. However the problem is how should I deal with overlapping times

Comment: "Fire every day" at what time and how often? Once?

Comment: Provide the time or times that the requirement says it should fire as "2001-MM-DD XXXXXXX"

Comment: fire every day of the week outside of 16pm to 20pm. That means fire from 20 to 16 but not possible to express in crontabs

Comment: fire every day at what time of day and how often? What is the next time to fire "2001-MM-DD XXXXXXX"

Comment: fire every day from 20pm to 16pm and every event that enter during this timespan.

Comment: every second? every minute? every hour? once? repeatedly? why don't you actually list the times in the format "2001-01-01 hh:mm:ss" so it is possible to see.

Comment: Im using the crontab expression (* ,16:20, * ,* ,*) means between 16hrs and 20hrs every day of the year every second, every minute and every month.

Comment: maybe what you mean is that you want to always fire when an event A arrives, except between 4pm and 8pm? In this case you could have a context that starts at 8pm and ends at 4pm?